# Nginx (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream

Tags: python, nginx, flask

```
# error message
[error] 21#21: *3 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream,
```

```
# nginx/nginx.conf
server {
    listen 1234;
    client_body_buffer_size 10M;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:900;
    }
}
```

```
# docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.7"

services:

  flask:
    build: ./flask
    container_name: flask
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 900

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:1234"
```

Hello. I made two images on EC2 ubuntu 18.04 server. And the processes of 'build' and 'up' are successful. But, I cannot have a connection from my local PC with API POST.

Above all are my error messages and main configure files. Please help the beginner developer .. Always Thanks alot to Stackoverflowers.

Comment: Maybe try proxy_pass instead of uwsgi_pass ? I had some problems too using uwsgi_pass with a docker setup like yours.